# .htaccess file (save request_filename) as querystring

Tags: .htaccess

I am using my htaccess file to forward users to a specific page when they request a notfound page. So far i have this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.asp
```

I also want to pass the bad filename that they tried to use to this page using a querystring value. So I want something like

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.asp?badfilename=HERE
```

I have been trying to play wround with URL rewrite and using %{Request_Filename} but I am new to working with .htaccess code. Is it possible to pass the bad filename to the notfound.asp with the bad file name as a querystring value? (I have code in my notfound.asp page that will retrieve the bad file name querystring value for tracking purposes.)

Comment: I made this change in my htaccess file and this worked great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /notfound.asp?badfilename=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)